# Как перейти из окна A в окно B и выявить специфический tab Bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap, href

Необходимо перейти из окна при нажатии на кнопку 3 в окне B.
Из 6 `tabs` будет показан таб номер 3, который мы выбрали в предыдущем окне.

`<button>` window A:

```
<button id="button3">Tab3</button>
$("#button3").click(function(){
 var url = "windowB.html";
 window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```

Bootstrap `tabs` window B:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#0">History of Football - The Origins</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#1">The History of the FIFA World Cup™</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#2">History of Football - Britain, the home of Football</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#3">History of Football - Opposition to the Game</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#4">The first kings of the world</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#5">Jules Rimet Cup</a></li>

        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Обычно этот вид данных передается через [параметры адресной строки](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8). 
Например: `script.php?tab=3` или `script.html#3`